# Dart Aqueduct Rest API Unit Testing: Null Safety Error

Tags: rest, dart, aqueduct

I have created a simple REST Api using aqueduct and dart and I am attempting to run unit tests. However, I get the following error when trying to do so:

```
Failed to load "test\example_test.dart":
  Unable to spawn isolate: Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
  don't support null safety:

   - package:test_core
   - package:test_api
   - package:aqueduct_test
   - package:test
   - package:aqueduct
   - package:boolean_selector
   - package:logging
   - package:safe_config
   - package:matcher
   - package:crypto
   - package:password_hash
   - package:open_api
   - package:yaml
   - package:postgres
   - package:convert
   - package:codable
   - package:pub_semver
```

My Code is as follows:

channel.dart

```
Controller get entryPoint {
    final router = Router();

    // Prefer to use `link` instead of `linkFunction`.
    // See: https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/request_controller/
    router.route("/example").linkFunction((request) async {
      return Response.ok({"key": "value"});
    });
```

example_test.dart

```
import 'harness/app.dart';

Future main() async {
  final harness = Harness()..install();

  test("GET /example returns 200 {'key': 'value'}", () async {
    expectResponse(await harness.agent.get("/example"), 200, body: {"key": "value"});
  });
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your Dart version is >2.12

Aqueduct does not support null safety. So basically you cannot go about it as it is. You need to install dart version which is lower than 2.12. I would suggest 2.7.2 as there were some breaking changes from 2.8 and above which mess things up in Aqueduct.

A better solution is to install dart 2.7.2 inside a docker container and use VS code for development.

And also it is better to note that Stabelkernel has [discontinued](https://stablekernel.com/article/announcing-the-sunsetting-of-aqueduct-our-open-source-server-side-framework-in-googles-dart/) development of Aqueduct and it wont be supported.

There is a community effort to fork aqueduct and rebrand it as [Conduit](https://github.com/conduit-dart/conduit). Hopefully a null safe initial release of Conduit is around the corner. So an eye for that too.